# What is the official way of installing IIS and required modules on windows server 2019 with powershell

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, windows-server-2019

I cant find a definitive way to install and configure IIS on server 2019

```
Add-WindowsFeature
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature
Install-WindowsFeature
is dism still a thing?
```

I need to install IIS with the following modules:

- asp-net-45
- dynamic compression
- all management tools
- need to enable remote management so I can deploy to it with webdeploy

I see examples with all the above tools but seems some are wrong/outdated

Starting fresh with 2019 what is the correct command/tools to install and configure IIS via a script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Install-WindowsFeature` and  is what you need. However it does the same thing as `Add-WindowsFeature`. `Install-WindowsFeature` is the modern equivalent for installing a feature onto a running operating system.

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` is equivalent to the older `dism` commands. It can also be applied to offline Windows images (such as a WIM)

Comment: finally a definitive answer lol. so I can install IIS and all those modules (on server 2019) with just the Install-WindowsFeature command?

Comment: You can do everything except the remote management part with `Install-WindowsFeature`. The remote management part of IIS sucks, and AFAIK it is still done by manipulating IIS directly by installing the remote management modules.